# Number only decreases twice?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, setinterval

I'm having quite a few issues with my code.. Here's my code.

```
    var playerDogHealth = [10, 10, 10];
    var playerDogAttentionAll = [10, 10, 0];
    function healthDecreaseTime() {
        // Health, Hunger, Attention
        if (playerDogAttentionAll[0] == 0 <= 5) {
            playerDogHealth[0] = playerDogHealth[0] - 2;
        } else {
            playerDogHealth[0] = playerDogHealth[0] - 1;
        }
        console.log(playerDogHealth[0]);
    }
    setInterval(healthDecreaseTime(),1000);
    healthDecreaseTime();
```

When I look in the console, all I see is '9' and then '8' and then that's it.. it stops decreasing for some reason. Some help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try `setInterval(healthDecreaseTime,1000);` instead of `setInterval(healthDecreaseTime(),1000);`

Comment: @Zub you can post this as an answer

Comment: What is `playerDogAttentionAll[0] == 0 <= 5` supposed to be doing?

Comment: @ling.s, Qantas 94 Heavy did it faster :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `()` -- that will invokes the function and returns its result (`undefined`), rather than passing the function itself. If you don't pass the function to `setInterval` in the first place, how is it going to know what to call?

```
var playerDogHealth = [10, 10, 10];
var playerDogAttentionAll = [10, 10, 0];
function healthDecreaseTime() {
    // Health, Hunger, Attention
    if (playerDogAttentionAll[0] <= 5) {
        playerDogHealth[0] = playerDogHealth[0] - 2;
    } else {
        playerDogHealth[0] = playerDogHealth[0] - 1;
    }
    console.log(playerDogHealth[0]);
}
setInterval(healthDecreaseTime, 1000);
healthDecreaseTime();
```

Also, it seems that you've included `== 0` by accident, this should just be

```
if (playerDogAttentionAll[0] <= 5) {
```

In fact, you could just simplify that if-else condition into the following:

```
playerDogHealth[0] -= playerDogAttentionAll[0] <= 5 ? 2 : 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove `()`.

So instead of:

```
setInterval(healthDecreaseTime(),1000);
```

write:

```
setInterval(healthDecreaseTime,1000);
```

**UPDATE**:

`setInterval` requires first parameter to be a function.

So `healthDecreaseTime` == function

But `healthDecreaseTime()` == what the function returns (in your case `undefined`)

Comment: While it is a best practice to provide setInterval with a function as first parameter, it is not mandatory. Here is setInterval receiving an object as parameter: `var a = { toString : function() { return 'alert("OK")'} }; setInterval(a, 1000);`. This code alerts OK every second. I will let you explain why.

Comment: @Tibos maybe it is because setInterval also supports string of javascript code as the first parameter. Having an object with `toString` method will execute this method and get an `alert('OK')` string, which will be interpeted as javascript code. That's all I know :)

Comment: Actually it seems more interesting than i first thought. Obviously `a` is converted to the string 'alert("OK")' (by calling the toString method) which is then eval'd by setInterval. I had expected the conversion to be done by eval, but it seems to be done by the setInterval method instead. `eval(a)` will return `a`, as mentioned by MDN. New day, new obscure fact.